# Hide all taskbars and System tray on all connected monitors using Ctypes

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I am trying to hide the taskbar and the system tray on all the monitors I have connected (in this case 2 monitors).

When I try to do it on the foreground monitor there is no problem and everything works as expected.

Here is an example:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import time

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL("user32")

SW_HIDE = 0
SW_SHOW = 5

user32.FindWindowW.restype = wintypes.HWND
user32.FindWindowW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR, # lpClassName
    wintypes.LPCWSTR) # lpWindowName

user32.ShowWindow.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HWND, # hWnd
    ctypes.c_int)  # nCmdShow

def hide_taskbar():
    hWnd = user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)

def unhide_taskbar():
    hWnd = user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)

# Testing:
hide_taskbar()
time.sleep(2)
unhide_taskbar()
```

But this only works with the foreground Monitor (or monitor 1).

How could I do this for all monitors?

Comment: What happens when moving the window where you run the script to another monitor?

Comment: @CristiFati There is no window. The window is the taskbar itself. 
`user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)`

Comment: No, you didn't get my point. "***he window where you run the script***" meaning the *cmd* where you launched `python script.py`.

Comment: Mmmm... I am running this from an IDE. If I move the IDE to the other monitor and execute the code... nothing different happens. Only the taskbar of monitor 1 is hidden. The same thing happens if I run it from the command line on monitor 2. It only works with the first monitor