# Make the taskbar disappear on all monitors

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, taskbar

This code only removes the taskar on my laptop screen:

```py
from ctypes import WinDLL
user32 = WinDLL("user32")

SW_HIDE = 0
SW_SHOW = 5

# Hides the taskbar:
hWnd = user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)

# Shows the taskbar:
hWnd = user32.FindWindowW(u"Shell_traywnd", None)
user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)
```

In windows using python, how do I make the taskbar disappear on all monitors as well as my laptop screen, without using any extra python packages?

Someone asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235645/hide-all-taskbars-and-system-tray-on-all-connected-monitors-using-ctypes). But they got no answers.
The: `u"Shell_traywnd"` is evidently just for the laptop screen. I wonder if there is something similar to this that hides the taskbar on all monitors, but I haven't managed to find out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taskbars on secondary monitors have a different class name (Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd).

You should not hide the taskbars like this. If you create a window that fills the monitor area exactly then the shell will notice and hide the taskbar for you if you are a fullscreen application.